# Using libc++ instead of libstdc++ in an Adobe Flex native extension

Tags: c++, apache-flex, xcode4, standard-library, air-native-extension

We have a rather large c++ library that we packaged inside an Adobe Flex extension for use by our Flex users. We package that ANE for several platforms, including Mac OS and iOS. On the Mac, all is well when we build using the legacy standard C++ library (`libstdc++`). Of course we  don't want to stay with an obsolete soon-to-be unsupported library and we switched to the current `libc++`. The library  (.a file) builds fine that way, and so do the native iOS applications that call on that library.

However, the `adt` Adobe tool that builds ANEs now fail with no useful error message (don't start me on Adobe tools quality). Some trickery with Unix processes let us find out that `adt` calls the OS linker `ld`. Replicating the same `ld` invocation let us find out that the linker complains about a boatload of undefined symbols, all (or perhaps most) being standard C++ library symbols.

Indeed that `ld` invocation uses as a parameter `-lstdc++` which refers to the legacy library. I suppose that using libc++ would imply the `lc++` argument. However, trying such a modified `ld` failed due to (apparently) unrelated directory issues.

So is there a way to tell `adt` that our .a library uses the current standard C++ library and not the legacy one? Is there any sensible workaround for that `adt` limitation? More generally, is there a way to convince `adt` (and Flex Builder in general) not to intercept and eat the tools error messages?

Any suggestion welcome. This is using Xcode 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

In the `platformoptions.xml` file for the iPhone-ARM target, try adding the `-lc++` option.  I.e., a minimal `platformoptions.xml` file would look like this:

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.1">
    <sdkVersion>4.0.0</sdkVersion>
    <linkerOptions>
        <option>-lc++</option>
    </linkerOptions>
</platform>
```

Your build command would be something like this:

`adt -package -target ane Output.ane extension.xml -swc anelib.swc -platform iPhone-ARM -C ios . -platformoptions platformoptions.xml`